# How to create a hierarchy reactive table and menu in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, hierarchy

I want to do a hierarchy menu with a reactive table output. I want my app to do things below:

1. when I choose the `brand = w`, the model input I can choose should only be lower hierarchy of w (in this case: `model` should be `w123` and `w456`), and the table output should be the subset of `brand w`
2. when I choose the brand = w and model = w123 together, and table output should list the subset of `brand = w & model = w123`

here are my codes, could anyone help me? thanks

**ui：**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI((fluidPage(
   titlePanel("hirearchy data group"),
   sidebarLayout
   (
   sidebarPanel
   (
   selectInput("brand",label="choice the brand",choices=c("all","w","s")),
   selectInput("model",label="choice the model",choices=c("all","w123","w456","s99","s88"))

   ),

   mainPanel
   (
   dataTableOutput("table")
   )

   ))))
```

**server：**

```
library(shiny)

## test dataframe
df <- data.frame(id = c("1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2"),
                 brand = c("w","w","w","s","s","s","w","w","w","s"),
                 model = c("w123","w123","w456","s99","s88","s88","w123","w456","w456","s99"),
                 amount = c(10,9,7,8,6,4,7,3,2,8))
df$id=as.character(df$id)
df$brand=as.character(df$brand)
df$model=as.character(df$model)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {
   output$table <- renderDataTable({ 
      if(input$brand!="all") {df=df[which(df$brand==input$brand),]}
      if(input$model!="all") {df=df[which(df$model==input$model),]}

   df

   })

})
```

Comment: Check out `?conditionalPanel`. You could use it to create separate `selectInput`s for `model`, and select which one to show based on the value of `brand`.

Comment: Another option would be to use `updateSelectInput` to change the available selections in the `selectInput` for `model` based on the value of `brand`.

Comment: On further thought, `updateSelectInput` would definitely be the way to go. Using `conditionalPanel` would only cause problems with different input ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code to your server:

```
  # This gets re-evaluated when input$brand changes
  observeEvent(input$brand, {
    brand <- input$brand

    # Available model options based on brand
    choices <- switch(brand, "w" = c("all","w123","w456"),
                             "s" = c("all","s99","s88"),
                           "all" = c("all","w123","w456","s99","s88"))

    # Update the model input object to only display wanted choices                  
    updateSelectInput(session, "model", choices = choices)
  })
```

In order for `updateSelectInput` to work, you also need to modify your server function definition to include the `session` object: your server definition should read as `shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {`.