# How can I pass a vector of character string labels, taken from an input data frame, as options in a checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r, shiny

So im trying to take an input file, read the column names, and return them as the options in a `checkboxGroupInput()`.

It currently extracts the column names and returns them as a vector of character strings, but I can't get it to use that vector as the options in a `checkboxGroupInput`.

Note: The actual code for the server uses `read.csv(file = file1$datapath)` with an uploaded file (and works properly), but I don't know how to include the .csv file in this replication. So I tried to use `read.table()` and a text representation of the data frame here for the sake of creating a reproducible example (may not work perfectly).

```
library(shiny)

df <- "substrate rep treatment time RFU
1             1   1      live  9:56 137,813.04
2             1   2      live  9:57 135,673.5
3             1   3      live  9:57 138,597.51
4             1 kill    killed 9:57 138,111.29
5             2   1      live  9:58 131,257.6
6             2   2      live  9:58 129,746.85"

ui <- fluidPage( 

  titlePanel("File Upload"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput(inputId = "data", label = "Data")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("names")
    ),
    checkboxGroupInput("design.variables", "Design Variables",
                       uiOutput("names")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  nms <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$data
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    d_uncal <- read.table(file = df
                        header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    nm <- names(d_uncal)
    nm
  })

  output$names <- renderPrint({
    if(is.null(nms()))
      return()
    else
      nms()

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Just figured it out.  I needed to create the ```checkboxGroupInput()``` as part of the server;
```output$designvars <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(nms())) return()
    else
    checkboxGroupInput("design.variables", "Select Design Variables", nms())```

Then create space in the UI with ```uiOutput("designvars")```

Answer (score 0):

I can't get your example to run, there seems to be a couple of errors. However, here's a brief description of what you could try to fix your problem.

You can use `updateCheckboxGroupInput` to change the values for input choices after you read in the file. Assuming your `nms()` reactive object is working, you could add this block after it:

```
observeEvent(nms(), {
  updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "design.variables", choices = nms())
})
```

This would then update the value of `choices` on your `checkboxGroupInput` whenever `nms()` changes. An additional change you need to do, is to pass the `session` object to your server by specifying the server function as:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) { ... # Everyhing else }
```

Check out my answer to a similar question regarding updating input values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501867/how-to-create-a-hierarchy-reactive-table-and-menu-in-shiny/31519419#31519419) for another example of using the `update*` functions.

PS. `uiOutput` is used to create ui elements from the output given by `renderUI`. `renderPrint` creates a character string containing the printed output that you would normally see on the console - to display the text in the ui, you have to use the `textOutput` function.

Comment: I think there was an error with the way I tried throwing the data frame in versus uploading one.